# Why is my function in Wordpress not working?

Tags: wordpress

Why not work my function in wordpress?

My code

```
add_post_meta( $ids, 'price', $price, true );
$price_add = get_post_meta($id, 'price', true);

function myprice(){
    if ($price_add != ' '){
        echo $price_add." Euro";
    }
    else {
        echo "None";
    }
}
```

I try use if (isset($price_add)) but not work.

I want to show price introduced in  or show text "None".

Comment: What you want to expect from the function `myprice()`?

Comment: I want to show price introduced in <input type="text" name="price" id="price"/> or show text "None".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are attempting to use a variable which is not "in scope". You might want to read the PHP manual page on [variable scope](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php).

A function is a reusable piece of code, with input and output, and in PHP variables are "scoped" (visible) to the function they are declared in. (The main exception is global variables, which are usually frowned on as they make code hard to read, reuse, and test; static variables and object members work a bit differently.)

In your case, you want a function which takes as input a price, and echoes that price if it is not an empty string (or, as you've written it, a single space); you might define that like this:

```
function myprice($price_to_display) {
    if ($price_to_display != ' '){
        echo $price_to_display." Euro";
    }
    else {
        echo "None";
    }
}
```

You then call that somewhere else, passing in the value you want to display, like this:

```
$price_add = get_post_meta($id, 'price', true);
myprice($price_add);
```

Note that I've named the variable in the function something different for clarity; you could call it `$price_add`, but that wouldn't make it connected to the other variable called `$price_add` in any special way.

*[Edited to add...]* In fact, you don't need to have a variable at all when you are calling the function - what you are providing is a *value* for the input parameter. So you could also write it like this:

```
myprice( get_post_meta($id, 'price', true) );
```

Comment: Not work. I used this code: function show_price($show_my_price){

    if ($show_my_price != ""){
        echo $show_my_price." EURO"; 
    }
    else {echo "Note";}
}<?php show_price($show_my_price); ?>... displaying as empty (none echo).

Comment: @golaz It's hard to say without seeing the actual code, in context, but `show_price($show_my_price);` seems wrong - you were previously using `$price_add = get_post_meta($id, 'price', true);`, so it would need to be `show_price($price_add);`. Note the difference between the variable being passed from the *outside* code *into* the function, and its name *inside the function*. You could also write `show_price( get_post_meta($id, 'price', true) );`

Comment: @golaz Also, try just writing `var_dump( get_post_meta($id, 'price', true) );` to check that the value you think you're passing in is actually set in the first place...

Comment: Code work: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22144018/custom-field-function-wordpress