# Custom Field function wordpress

Tags: wordpress

How create corect function with this code?

```
<?php $price = get_post_meta($id, 'price_input', true);

    if ($price != ''){
        echo $price . " Euro";
    }
    else {
        echo "None";
    }
 ?>
```

I want to put this code in function.php or another place and use `<?php myfunction(); ?>`

Thx for answer!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's pretty straight forward PHP:

```
#in functions.php
function display_price( $post_id ){
    $price = get_post_meta($post_id, 'price_input', true);

    if ($price != ''){
        echo $price . " Euro";
    }
    else {
        echo "None";
    }
}
```

in your template:

```
<?php display_price( $id ); ?>
```